# reading in text file and spliting by comma in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file whose format is like this

```
Number,Name,Age
```

I want to read "Number" at the first column of this text file into an array to find duplication. here is the two ways i tried to read in the file.

```
 string[]  account = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 string readtext = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

But every time i try to split the array to just get whats to the left of the first comma i fail. Have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly split the data to access its various parts. How would your program otherwise be able to decide that it is separated by commas?

The easiest approach to access the number that comes to my mind goes something like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var firstLine = lines[0];
var fields = firstLine.Split(',');
var number = fields[0]; // Voilla!
```

You could go further by parsing the number as an int or another numeric type (if it really is a number). On the other hand, if you just want to test for uniqueness, this is not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all duplicate lines according to the `Number`:

```
var numDuplicates = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Trim().Split(','))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 3)
    .Select(arr => new { 
        Number = arr[0].Trim(),
        Name   = arr[1].Trim(),
        Age    = arr[2].Trim()
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

foreach(var dupNumGroup in numDuplicates)
    Console.WriteLine("Number:{0} Names:{1} Ages:{2}"
        , dupNumGroup.Key
        , string.Join(",", dupNumGroup.Select(x => x.Name))
        , string.Join(",", dupNumGroup.Select(x => x.Age)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically for a `string.split` solution, here is a really simple method of doing what you are looking for:

```
List<int> importedNumbers = new List<int>();
// Read our file in to an array of strings
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
// Iterate over the strings and split them in to their respective columns
foreach (string line in fileContents)
{
      var fields = line.Split(',');
      if (fields.Count() < 3)
          throw new Exception("We need at least 3 fields per line."); // You would REALLY do something else here...
      // You would probably want to be more careful about your int parsing... (use TryParse)
      var number = int.Parse(fields[0]);
      var name = fields[1];
      var age = int.Parse(fields[2]);
      // if we already imported this number, continue on to the next record
      if (importedNumbers.Contains(number))
          continue;  // You might also update the existing record at this point instead of just skipping...
      importedNumbers.Add(number); // Keep track of numbers we have imported
}
```